# How to restrict user from changing current date

Tags: php, codeigniter

My file tracking system deals with application submission. Date of the application is used to track total days taken to process each application. However, event though current date is shown, user able to change it to past date in my system. The system use mvc framework. What should i do to make the date inaccessible by user? Something like static.

Comment: You can manually insert date in `controller` before saving data.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the date against the application id in the database when the application is first submitted and then ignore any mention of the date in the submitted form data.

Comment: I cannot do that. File movement from one person to another person required date. Each user need to fill the form with current date and submit in the system. Thats y i want to make the date field to capture current date and user cannot change it manually

Comment: If you want to capture the date of the edit (rather than the initial submission), then just record the time the server receives it, there is no need to include it in the form data. The server has a clock.

Comment: Date count starts from initial submission and subsequently date when user update file information. Time not necessary

Comment: The clock gives you the date as well.

Comment: Thanks. Anything will come back later